# .htaccess RewriteRule with extra url param

Tags: .htaccess

Today I have following line in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^test.html default.php?page=10&language=en
```

I want:
`test.html` -> `default.php?page=10&language=en`

(this line is working fine)

And if test.html is called with extra url param then I want to add them, like this:

`test.html?user_id=ABC&currency=EUR` -> `default.php?page=10&language=en&user_id=ABC&currency=EUR`

(this line is not working, because I don't get `user_id=ABC&currency=EUR`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^test.html default.php?page=10&language=en [QSA,L]
```

With `[QSA|qsappend]`:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html